# totals.getSegment('giftcardaccount') returning null

Tags: magento2, javascript, knockoutjs, adobe-commerce

I'm about at my whits end.

I still consider myself a relative novice with Magento, but this one literally has me baffled.  I've also tossed it around to some senior devs at my work, and they are stumped too.

Locally, I've been using [Mark Shust's Docker](https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento) configuration setup for our sandbox.  After taking over the project (the previous developer is no longer involved in the project in any capacity what-so-ever), we transitioned the client from 2.4.3 up to 2.4.5-p1.  *Lots* of things broke with the PHP change and required module updates, but we've worked through them for the most part -- except for their custom gift cards module.

It's a customized module due to the fact that they run the gift cards through their own system because they are physical and not the standard virtual cards.  They also have a PIN number that's required as well.  Anyway... Long story short... this is all working fine on my local Docker system -- but not matter what I've tried, it does not *100%* work on either the Staging/Prod environments.  I should mention that it's running on the Adobe Commerce Cloud system.  They have been... *less than helpful* in trying to diagnose the whole issue let's just say.

Here is on my local after applying a test card:
[image: sandbox]

And here it is on Staging.
[image: staging]

The amount is being deducted correctly, but as you'll notice, the gift card itself and the ability to remove it is not appearing in the Order Summary on the right.

The problem appears to stem from the `isAvailable` method and the fact that `totals.getSegment('giftcardaccount') && totals.getSegment('giftcardaccount').value != 0;` returns nothing on Stage.

While it returns a full object on my local Sandbox.  I'm... stumped.

---

**[EDIT]**
May not come as much of a surprise with my above comments, but just to further confirm that that totals.getSegment('giftcardaccount') is null... here's the totals object in local vs. stage:

[image]

Comment: Maybe configuration difference in your local and STG. Check the magento log as well. Any browser console log?

Comment: I'm convinced it's a difference in the env. config, but I can't get the help from Adobe I'm looking for there.  Not really sure where to check and what.  I've looked through the /var/log/* directory on Stg many times and found nothing.  

Console has only a single, non-descriptive error that I can't rule out, but have also not been able to track down either `Blocked script execution in 'about:blank' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set.`. TBH... I don't know if that has anything to do with it or not... that error occurs on other pages too.